# Display the text of a button when clicked in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, button

I have a table made of buttons and each button has a text on it. However, I want that text to be invisible unless the button is clicked.
The buttons look like this:

```
<Button
            android:background="@drawable/roundstyle"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/c1"
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/i"
            tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml"
            android:onClick="displayText" />
```

In MainActivity, I tried to implement a function to display the text:

```
    fun displayText(view: View) {
        val b = view as Button
        val buttonText = b.text.toString()
```

I think the easiest thing to do would be to use "if", so that if btnOne is not clicked, then the text should be invisible, else, the text should be visible. But I am not sure **where** to write this code in the Main Activity and how exactly, so that once the button has been clicked, the text remains on the screen.
Could someone help me with this, please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can try this one by default set the button like this(the most easy solution)

```
<Button
            android:background="@drawable/roundstyle"
            android:backgroundTint="@color/c1"
            android:id="@+id/btnOne"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:tag = "some text"
            tools:ignore="UsingOnClickInXml"
            android:onClick="displayText" />
```

and click handler

```
fun displayText(view: View) {
       val b = view as Button
       val btnTag= b.tag.toString()
       if (b.text.isEmpty()) {
         b.text = btnTag
       }
}
```

Comment: I tried to, but I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, which I don't have yet:( It only shows that my feedback has been recorded. I'll see what to do to get that and make sure to upvote it:)

Comment: ok, i see, no problem))

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simply by changing the font size of the button text. you can initially set the font size to 0 and then set the right value after user clicked on it.

```
 <Button
        android:onClick="displayText"
        android:text="Sample Text"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:textSize="0sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

To visible the text once

```
fun displayText(view: View) {       
        view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,12f)
    }
```

This function will toggle the visibility of the text

```
fun displayText(view: View) {
        if(view.textSize == 0f){
            view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,12f)
        }else{
            view.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP,0f)
        }
    }
```